# Typescript error - getElementsByTagName() return NodeListOf <Element> instead of HTMLCollectionOf<Element>

Tags: typescript, resharper, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

According to lib.dom.d.ts, getElementsByTagName() will return HTMLCollectionOf, but I run this line of code:

```
var lessonList: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lesson");
```

and I will get this error

```
TS 2322 Type NodeListOf <Element> is not assignable to type HTMLCollectionOf <Element> site:stackoverflow.com
```

By the way, I am using Webstorm 2018.3

Comment: What HTML element is Element?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in Visual Studio 2017 with ReSharper 2018.2. It seems that Intellisense thinks that `getElementsByTagName` returns a _NodeListOf<T>_ while TypeScript believes it returns _HTMLCollectionOf_. The one similarity between our environments is JetBrains, so it could be something in their products...

Comment: I also have this issue. I am using VSCode. I am compiling the TypeScript programmatically with browserify and tsify.